# Plot two barplot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

```
 data <- as.matrix(data.frame("A" = c(18,7),
                                "B+" = c(3,2),
                                "B" = c(3,3),
                                "C+" = c(6,0),
                                "C" = c(7,0),
                                "D" = c(0,4),
                                "E" = c(5,23)))
    
    
    barplot (data,
            col = c("red","blue"),
            beside = TRUE,
            xlab = "Grade",
            ylab = "Frequency")
    
    
    legend("topleft",
           c("IFC6503-A","IFC6510"),
           fill = c("red","blue"),
           inset = c(.01,0)
    )
```

I plot two barplot together, the barplot it contain grade, from two different data, the grade is by A B+ B C+ C D E , but the result  B+ and C+ is not appear, just appear B. and C. , is my code is wrong or can you guys correct my code?

Answer (score 5):

Do not use special character `+` in colnames as already pointed by Bernhard:
Here is a way where you could relabel the x axis of the plot by hand:

1. Give adequate colnames in your matrix: see here comment of whuber: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163280/naming-convention-for-column-names
2. use `xaxt = "n"` in barplot to remove x labels
3. use `axis` to insert x labels manually:

```
data <- as.matrix(data.frame("A" = c(18,7),
                             "Bplus" = c(3,2),
                             "B" = c(3,3),
                             "Cplus" = c(6,0),
                             "C" = c(7,0),
                             "D" = c(0,4),
                             "E" = c(5,23)))


barplot (data,
         col = c("red","blue"),
         beside = TRUE,
         xlab = "Grade",
         ylab = "Frequency",
         xaxt = "n")
         
axis(1, at = seq(2, 20, 3), labels = c("A", "B+", "B", "C+", "C", "D", "E"))


legend("topleft",
       c("IFC6503-A","IFC6510"),
       fill = c("red","blue"),
       inset = c(.01,0)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Or `labels=gsub('plus', '+', colnames(data))` to avoid typos.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the columns in the `data` doesn't have `B+` and `C+`

You can just rename the columns like this after loading the file:

```
colnames(data)[2] <-'B+'
colnames(data)[4] <-'C+'
```

Now plot with the same code

```
barplot (data,
         col = c("red","blue"),
         beside = TRUE,
         xlab = "Grade",
         ylab = "Frequency")


legend("topleft",
       c("IFC6503-A","IFC6510"),
       fill = c("red","blue"),
       inset = c(.01,0)
)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: +1 good solution for the plot but overall not a good idea to use column names with a `+` or a space or ... in it.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(
    name = str_replace(name,"\\.","+"),
    grp = row_number(),
    grp = if_else(grp == 1,"IFC6503-A","IFC6510")
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value,fill = grp))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("IFC6503-A" = "red","IFC6510" = "blue"))+
  labs(
    x = "Grade",
    y = "Frequency"
  )
```

[image]